# How to ensure my app don't send out too many notifications

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, settings

I'm developing an iOS activity app that will utilize notifications in many different cases (eg. you have a new follower, you have received a new like, someone have commented on your activity) - each notification category can be individually turn on/off by the user in the app settings.

As most users will not spend too much time editing the notifications settings I would like to implement some form of limit to the number of notifications that will be sent to an individual user over a set time interval.

Eg. A user has posted a message and he/she receives lets say 10 likes over 30 minutes. Sending a notification for each like seems a bit excessive. Maybe the first like should send a notification, but then maybe the next notification should be minimum 30 minutes later. So if several likes has been received in the mean time the next notification should say "you have received X number of likes".

I might want to limit the number of likes per category, but also overall for the app. Then there might be some categories that is important to send directly independent of overall limits.

I'm definitely not the first to try to solve this problem, but I have not found any good sources of information. Do anyone have any best practice examples to share for how to handle this? or a good tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best practice, but I would solve it this way.

Scenario 1 - checking last time sent: On the backend I will keep the last notification sent time for the target. According to this, you may decide whether you will send a new notification or not.

Scenario 2 - time frame: If you want to implement sth like 10 messages in 30 minutes, no matter the distance between them, it is more or less the same. You will have to add every notification you have sent to the target to your database. If a new one should be sent, you will erase all records older than 30 minutes and check if count is less than your threshold.

It is not the 100 percent what you asked, but might give you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a debouncer for this. The debouncer prevents the method a.k.a. the notification from firing to often in a certain time period.

Debounce class:

```
final class Debounce: NSObject {
    var callback: (() -> ())
    var delay: Double
    weak var timer: Timer?

    init(_ callback: @escaping (() -> ()), delay: Double = 0.25) {
        self.delay = delay
        self.callback = callback
    }

    func call() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        let nextTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: delay, target: self, selector: #selector(Debounce.fireNow), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        timer = nextTimer
    }

    @objc func fireNow() {
        self.callback()
    }
}
```

Usage example would be:

```
var sendNotificationDebounce: Debounce?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchTermDebounce = Debounce({ [weak self] in
        guard let `self` = self else {
            return
        }
        self.sendNotification()
    }, delay: 300) // delay is in seconds (300 would be 5 mins)
}

func sendNotification() {
    // sends notification
}

func someOtherMethod() {
    sendNotificationDebounce?.call()
}
```